# Fn+Vol and Fn+Brightness not working on Asus r510l

Tags: 14.04, shortcuts

I have Kubuntu 14.04 64bit on new Asus r510l laptop but unable to use Fn+vol and Fn+brightness keys. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>FVol</kbd> shows the indicator but does not have any effect all while <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>brightness</kbd> doesn't do anything. I am new to using Linux so any help to fix these problems will be deeply appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your Terminal and type `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`.
2. Then search for

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=
   ```

   and append `acpi_osi=Linux` to make it looks similar to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
3. Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

It should work for Asus as for Acer PCs too.